# How to print an inverted triangle?

Tags: c++, loops

I am learning c++ programming these days hence I got myself a book to learn it. I have completed the Flow control chapter which describes the use of if else loops etc.
I am stuck at this particular question:-

`Write a Program To print the following :-`

```
@@@@@@@
 @@@@@
  @@@
   @
```

How can I accomplish this using only loops and if else statements in c++.

I figured out that in every row there are two less @'s and one more space.

I have also programmed for the repeating @'s but  I am unable to insert the spaces. Here's my program for @'s:-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 7; i > 0; i = i - 2) {

        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {

            cout << "@" << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just compute from `i` how many spaces you'll need and insert them with another loop before you start to print out the `@` characters. You seem to have `k` already declared for this (which is unused in your code currently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a string variable with nothing at the start and in the first cycle (before the second) write: (as a string variable g)

```
cout << g;
```

And after the second cycle but **in** the first

```
g+=" ";
```

And you'll get your triangle. :)

Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string g="";
    for(int i=7; i>0; i-=2)
    {
        cout << g;
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            cout << "@";
        }
        cout << endl;
        g+=" ";
    }
    cout << "Press a button to exit..." << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope you'll understand my english. :)

Comment: Nice and simple It uses very basic things and it was a lot easier to understand than other answers Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My approach

```
#include <iostream>
static const int FIRST_ROW = 15;

int main()
{
    for (int i = FIRST_ROW; i > 0; i -= 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (FIRST_ROW - i) / 2; ++j)
            std::cout << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            std::cout << "@";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but will you explain what happens in the code? and your algorithm you used @Zereges

Comment: @Adityaultra You probably want to step though this code line by line using the debugger, to see how it works.

Comment: Which debugger i am currently compiling through gcc and am running linux @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Adityaultra _"Which debugger"_ `gdb`. If you're using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) it's probably integrated.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of a little bit different approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string spaces = string();
    string chars = string(7, '@');
    while (chars.size() > 0) {
        cout << spaces << chars << endl;
        spaces += ' ';
        chars.erase(max(chars.size(), 2u) - 2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```